# What php datastructure is this?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable/data structure in its **original** state, that when var_dump() 'ed', looks like this:

```
string 'some name' (length=13)

string 'another name ' (length=16)

string 'another name ' (length=11)
```

I have a function that gets the same names and pre-pends a letter to them. The results are stored in an array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  1 => 
   array (size=1)
    'name' => string 'A - the name ' (length=20)
  2 => 
   array (size=1)
    'name' => string 'A - the name ' (length=15)
  3 => 
   array (size=1)
    'name' => string 'C - the name' (length=17)
```

I need the modified data in the same state as the original.

How do I convert the array structure to look like the original?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to show us what you have tried and explain how that attempt failed?

Comment: Can you share your function, it may have another way to prepend text.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Just loop the array, split on `' - '` and get the string you want.

Comment: The values are *anonymous* so they probably are something that resides inside an array/list/dict/range object, otherwise they should've have a variable-name. Furthermore it might link to something Database related, as a list of column-names that reside inside a range-storage object `{ ... }`/`[ ... ]` and that they are read top-down, thus knowing no definitive structure.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to remove the letter?

```
foreach($myarrayname as $key => &$value) {
    $value = substr($value, 4);
}
```

To get a single element, use

```
$myarrayname[0] // for the first one, ...[1] for the second one and so on
```